# Parsing ISO Date String into ZoneDateTime with RestTemplate in Spring

Tags: java, spring, iso

I am making a GET request through a RestTemplate to fetch some data which contains a `dateCreated` field. The Date/Time is stored as an ISO Standard String in the following format:

```
2020-01-14T15:21:52.000+0530
```

However, the RestTemplate is unable to map this string to a *ZonedDateTime* Object on receiving it at this step:

```
ResponseEntity<OrderData[]> responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(urlGETList, OrderData[].class);
```

However, a similar mapping works fine when the ISO string is passed to a Controller which uses `@RequestBody` to map the ISO String to *ZonedDateTime* using the following objectMapper implementation

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    JavaTimeModule javaTimeModule = new JavaTimeModule();
    javaTimeModule.addSerializer(ZonedDateTime.class,
            new ZonedDateTimeSerializer(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX")));
    return Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.json().featuresToDisable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS) // ISODate
            .modules(javaTimeModule).build();
}
```

In the RestTemplate method, I encounter the following error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_VALUES
at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.JSR310DateTimeDeserializerBase.acceptCaseInsensitiveValues(JSR310DateTimeDeserializerBase.java:126)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.JSR310DateTimeDeserializerBase.createContextual(JSR310DateTimeDeserializerBase.java:86)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.InstantDeserializer.createContextual(InstantDeserializer.java:241)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handlePrimaryContextualization(DeserializationContext.java:651)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.resolve(BeanDeserializerBase.java:484)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:293)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findContextualValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:444)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.ObjectArrayDeserializer.createContextual(ObjectArrayDeserializer.java:128)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleSecondaryContextualization(DeserializationContext.java:682)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:482)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._findRootDeserializer(ObjectMapper.java:4190)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4009)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3084)
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:237)
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:225)
at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:95)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:917)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:901)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:655)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:613)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForEntity(RestTemplate.java:312)
at com.increff.assure.service.ClientWrapper.getOrdersByChannel(ClientWrapper.java:111)
at com.increff.assure.dto.OrderDto.getByChannel(OrderDto.java:57)
at com.increff.assure.controller.ChannelOrderController.getByChannel(ChannelOrderController.java:42)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
... 43 more
```

What is preventing the serializing the ISO Date/Time String?

Comment: Remove 2 of the `X`es at the end of your pattern... And consider using an `OffsetDateTime` instead of a `ZonedDateTime` when you parse `String`s that contain an offset but no zone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the JSON received through the `RestTemplate` couldn't figure out how to parse the ISO DateTime String it received to a `ZonedDateTime` object.

I found the solution by including a **custom** `ZonedDateTimeDeserializer` in the `ObjectMapper` to parse ISO format strings to `ZonedDateTime`. Although a `ZonedDateTimeSerializer` is pre-provided and fully implemented, I couldn't find a `ZonedDateTimeDeserialzer`. So my custom deserializer takes care of that

```
public class ZonedDateTimeDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<ZonedDateTime> {
    @Override
    public ZonedDateTime deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext)
            throws IOException {
        return ZonedDateTime.parse(
                jsonParser.getText(),
                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX")
        );
    }
}
```

Next, I add this deserializer to my `ObjectMapper`.

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    JavaTimeModule javaTimeModule = new JavaTimeModule();
    javaTimeModule.addSerializer(ZonedDateTime.class,
            new ZonedDateTimeSerializer(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX")));
    javaTimeModule.addDeserializer(ZonedDateTime.class,
            new ZonedDateTimeDeserializer());
    ObjectMapper objMapper = Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.json().featuresToDisable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS) // ISODate
            .modules(javaTimeModule).build();
    return objMapper;
}
```

This handles the parsing of `ZonedDateTime` when using `RestTemplate` perfectly.